# jQuery : get the content between a child and end of its parent and wrap that into a div

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="article-content">
                <p>content of article</p>
                <h3 id="last-heading"></h3>

                <p>Content part 1 of last heading</p>
                <p>Content part 2 of last heading</p>
                <a href="http://www.google.co.in">Link</a>
                <div class="article-img"><img src="imgurl"/></div>...

        ..
        ..
        ..

            </div>
```

I want to get the content between element with id last-heading to the end of its parent #article-content and wrap that into a div with id #processed-content

Output Expected:

```
<div id="article-content">
            <p>content of article</p>
            <h3 id="last-heading"></h3>
            <div id="processed-content">
            <p>Content part 1 of last heading</p>
            <p>Content part 2 of last heading</p>
            <a href="http://www.google.co.in">Link</a>
            <div class="article-img"><img src="imgurl"/></div>...

    ..
    ..
    ..
</div>
        </div>
```

How to achieve this using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe like this,

```
$("#last-heading").nextAll().wrapAll("<div id='processed-content'></div>");
```

`nextAll()` will get all the siblings after the current element. Then you can use `wrapAll()` to wrapt the elements with a particular element

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/275/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#processed-content").html($('#last-heading').nextUntil());
```

If you have any value in  processed-content use append in jquery

```
$("#processed-content").append($('#last-heading').nextUntil());
```

or If you dont have  processed-content in your dom use like this

```
$('#last-heading').nextUntil().wrapAll( "<div id='processed-content' />")
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MsGgP/7/)